# FastExcel import additional field data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

***Code***

```
   public function import(Request $request)
{
    $id= $request->id;
    $limit = $request->limit;
    $path = $request->file('file')->store('uploads');
    $products = (new FastExcel)->import('public/' . $path, function ($line) {
        return Data::create([

            'uname' => $line['name'],
            'username' => $line['username'],
            'limit' => $limit,
            'group_id' =>$id 
        ]);
    });


    flash(__('Your products imported successfully'))->success();
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

Thhis is not woking id and limit not defined

I need solution for this im useing laravel 6.2 with FastExcel

Comment: why are you first strong the file then, the reading it from storage.
cant you directly read it ?

Comment: and i would also suggest you to use phpspreedsheet package. its more reliable and comes with a large community support.